# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Geolocation> has no method 'clearwatch'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, geolocation

I try to develop application with jquery mobile with phonegap. In first page register number is entered and then get the gps value using watchposition then update its location to sqlite database. in that i try to stop the watchposition using clearwatch() method. and i have the following error. 
    Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'clearwatch'
my index.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Geo position Aware Vehicle Locator</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/register.js"></script>
    <script src="js/terminate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/update.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            navigator.notification.alert("PhoneGap is ready!");
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#regis").click(register);
            $("#start").click(update);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <p align="center">Vehicle Registration</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <label>Give Route Number</label>
        <input type="text" id="rno"> <a href="#second" id="regis" data-transition="pop" data-role="button"
                                        data-inline="true" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-mini="true"
                                        data-theme="b">Register</a>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="second" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <p align="center">Vehicle Status</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
        <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
            <h1>Current Location:</h1>

            <h3> Latitude:</h3>

            <p id="lat"></p>

            <h3>Longitude:</h3>

            <p id="long"></p>

            <h3>Current Time:</h3>

            <p id="utime"></p> <a id="start" data-role="button" data-theme="b">start</a>
            <a id="terminate" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="b">Terminate</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

and my terminate.js

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    console.log("devicere");
    if (navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        console.log("check con");
        $("#terminate").text('No Internet Access')
            .attr("data-icon", "delete")
            .button('refresh');
    }

});

var rno = localStorage.getItem('rno');//get value from local storage
console.log("rno=>", rno);
var watch_id = '';    // ID of the geolocation
var tracking_data = []; // Array containing GPS position objects
$("#start").on('click', function () {
    watch_id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        // Success
        function (position) {
            console.log(position);
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            console.log("lat", lat);
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log("lon", lon);
            var utime = position.timestamp;
            console.log("position", utime);
            $("#lat").html(lat);
            $("#long").html(lon);
            $('#utime').html(utime);
            console.log('position' + lat + lon + utime);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/update",
                data: 'vid=' + rno + '&lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&utime=' + utime,
                cache: false
            });
        },

        // Error
        function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        // Settings
        { frequency: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
});   

//stop tracking gps value
$("#terminate").on('click', function () {
    navigator.geolocation.clearwatch(watch_id);
    var url = "/terminate";
    $(location).attr('href', url);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watch_id); with a capital "W" in Watch.